# r - how to remove vertices of one graph based on certain attributes of another graph

Tags: r, igraph, vertices

I have one graph with 693 vertices and another has 700 vertices. Second graph has vertices with labels that are not present in the first graph. How do I remove the extra vertices from the second graph. The labels are in the format of "J68", "I11"...

Answer (score 2):

You can identify which vertices are in the first graph and not in the second graph and then remove them as follows:

First let's create a couple of graphs to play with. The second graph will have a subset of the vertices in the first graph.

```
library(igraph)

# Create a couple of graphs (based on example in the igraph package help)
graph1 <- make_graph( ~ A-B-C-D-A, E-A:B:C:D, F-G-H-I-F, J-F:G:H:I,
                     K-L-M-N-K, O-K:L:M:N, P-Q-R-S-P, T-P:Q:R:S, B-F, 
                     E-J, C-I, L-T, O-T, M-S, C-P, C-L, I-L, I-P)

V(graph1)
```

> ```
> + 20/20 vertices, named:
>  [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
> ```

```
graph2 <- make_graph( ~ F-G-H-I-F, J-F:G:H:I, K-L-M-N-K, O-K:L:M:N,
                      P-Q-R-S-P, T-P:Q:R:S, L-T, O-T, M-S, I-L, I-P)

V(graph2)
```

> ```
> + 15/15 vertices, named:
>  [1] F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
> ```

Now, get names of vertices to remove. We want to remove the vertices in graph1 that are not in graph2:

```
remove = setdiff(names(V(graph1)), names(V(graph2)))

remove
```

> ```
> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
> ```

```
graph1 = delete.vertices(graph1, remove)

V(graph1)
```

> ```
> + 15/15 vertices, named:
>  [1] F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
> ```